# Test your Mobile App's Code

Tags: html5, ide

I am new to game development in HTML5, and I would like to know how I can test my code out to see what I made with an IDE or something. Thanks!

Comment: I imagine this is covered in any basic tutorial. What have you looked for already?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to load HTML5 in a web browser or an appropriate emulator or it's targeted toward a specific device